# Fill lines with a certain character until it contains a given amount of them

Tags: bash, file, unix, awk, sed

I have various flat files that contain roughly 30k records that I need to reformat using a script to ensure they all have the same amount of `~`'s.

For example below are two of the sample records in the flat file. The first record containing 8 ~'s and the second containing 10 ~'s.

```
736~company 1~cp1~1~19~~08/07/1878~09/12/2015~
658~company 2~cp2~1~19~65.12~27/06/1868~22/08/2015~address line 1~address line 2~
```

I need both records to contain 12 ~'s so I need code that will loop through the file add pad out each line to contain the correct number of ~'s. The desired result would be as follows.

```
736~company 1~cp1~1~19~~08/07/1878~09/12/2015~~~~~
658~company 2~cp2~1~19~65.12~27/06/1868~22/08/2015~address line 1~address line 2~~~
```

I have the following bit of code which will display the number of ~'s in each file but I'm sure how to proceed from here.

```
sed 's/[^~]//g' inputfile.text| awk '{ print length }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the field separator to `~` and keep adding `~`s until you have enough:

```
$ awk -F"~" -v cols=12 'NF<=cols{for (i=NF;i<=cols;i++) $0=$0 FS}1' file
736~company 1~cp1~1~19~~08/07/1878~09/12/2015~~~~~
658~company 2~cp2~1~19~65.12~27/06/1868~22/08/2015~address line 1~address line 2~~~
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, when I add that code into the shell script I get the following back. "awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1"

Comment: @cmac this is because you use an old awk. Instead, use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v FS='~' -v count=12 '{line = ""; for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) { line = line "~" $i } print line }' tildes.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here's a bash builtin-only solution:

```
a=~~~~~~~~~~~~;
while read -r line; do
  n=${line//[!~]};
  echo "$line${a/$n}";
done < file
```

#### Explanation

- `n=${l//[!~]}` makes a string from all `~` characters in `$l`.
- `${a/$n}` takes the string of 12 `~` characters and deletes the first match of `$n`, so when we append it to `$l`, there will be exactly 12 tildes in the echoed line.

Warning: If there are more than 12 tildes in one line in `file`, the corresponding outputted line will have more than 24 tildes in it, as there are no checks to make sure `${#n}` is less than `${#a}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F"~" -v c=12 'BEGIN{OFS=FS;c++}{$c=$c}1' file
736~company 1~cp1~1~19~~08/07/1878~09/12/2015~~~~~
658~company 2~cp2~1~19~65.12~27/06/1868~22/08/2015~address line 1~address line 2~~~
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.